How to Enable Edge-to-Edge Display Only for Specific Fragment in Android with Bottom Navigation?
I'm working on an Android app with an activity that contains a bottom navigation bar and three fragments. I want my HomeFragment to have an edge-to-edge display, but when I enable edge-to-edge mode in my base activity, it affects all the fragments, which is not what I want.
Here's what I've tried so far:

Base Activity with Edge-to-Edge Mode:

Enabling edge-to-edge mode in the base activity makes all fragments edge-to-edge.

Example: HomeFragment with edge-to-edge



Issue in Other Fragments:

Other fragments also inherit the edge-to-edge mode, which I don't want.

Example: Unwanted edge-to-edge in another fragment


This is my BaseActivity Code:
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SimActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val binding by lazy {
        ActivitySimBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setupBottomNavs()

    }

    private fun setupBottomNavs(){
        binding.bottomNav.selectedItemId = R.id.homeFragment // Set the default selected item to home
        setFragment(HomeFragment())
        binding.bottomNav.setOnItemSelectedListener(object : NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onNavigationItemSelected(newTab: MenuItem): Boolean {
                when (newTab.itemId) {
                    R.id.homeFragment -> {
                        switchFragment(HomeFragment())
                        return true
                    }
                    R.id.ordersFragment -> {
                        switchFragment(OrdersFragment())
                        return true
                    }
                    R.id.saleFragment -> {
                        switchFragment(SaleFragment())
                        return true
                    }
                }
                return false
            }
        })
    }

    private fun setFragment(homeFragment: HomeFragment) {
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.frameLayout,homeFragment) // Add this line
            .commitNow()
    }


    private fun switchFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        for (existingFragment in supportFragmentManager.fragments) {
            transaction.hide(existingFragment)
        }
        var showFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragment.javaClass.simpleName)
        if (showFragment == null) {
            showFragment = fragment
            transaction.add(R.id.frameLayout, showFragment, fragment.javaClass.simpleName)
        } else {
            transaction.show(showFragment)
        }
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()

    }


}



My goal is to enable edge-to-edge mode only when the HomeFragment is active and have the default status bar behaviour for the other fragments. How can I achieve this selectively?

You asked this question previously. Ian Lake responded, pointing out that edge-to-edge mode is for an activity (technically a window), so it will affect all of the fragments in that activity. You will need to deal with window insets for any fragment for which you do not want the content to go into the status bar. Also, please do not delete questions, then re-ask them.
